# Fix footer at the bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I would like fix footer at the bottom of the page, I tried 
CSS

```
 #footer {
    position: absolute;
    botom: 0;
}`
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">

    <div style="width: 155px; float: right;">
        <a href="http://zazoo.com/privacy/">Privée </a> | <a href="http://zazoo.com/terms-of-service/"> Conditions </a>
    </div>
</div>
<footer>
    <hr>
    <p>
        zAZOO est un service de sTELLA SAS, 40, rue Raymond debré, 93450, St denis,<br /> France, RCS 510 752 645 NANTERRE
    </p>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 3):

try this without id you have use to `footer` `html5` tag in this Demo

```
footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QpTYQ/1/)

OR

and with `#footer` you have use to below Demo.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QpTYQ/4/)

```
#footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First correct the typos. Next, the footer isn't an ID, but the name of the element, so you have to use:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/kqJrf/

Comment: Ok. You have multiple answer to choose from. let me give u an explanation. if you are refencing an element in CSS, dont use any prefix ex div{}, for a class use . ex .maindiv{}, for id use hash ex #maindiv.

Answer (score 0):

Your css needs minor edits. This is working.

```
 footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qVVWr/

Comment: The hr tag does not have a closing tag.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for the info. Updated it.

Answer (score 0):

The way that Fags say is good, but notice, that the footer element is for browser to understand the content of your page, not to style it. So better is to use it like this:

HTML

```
<footer id="main-footer">
    <p>Some Text is here</p>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
#main-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Second reason for giving an id or class to this element is, that if you use HTML5, you'll use more than one  element on page.